# Como selecionar as linhas de 1 a N anteriores

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho uma tabela gerada dinamicamente no seguinte esquema:

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row-1">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-2">
    <td>B</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-3">
    <td>C3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-total">
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Toogle">
    </td>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row-1">
    <td>D</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-2">
    <td>E</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-3">
    <td>F</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row-total">
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Toogle">
    </td>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Nessa tabela exibirei somente a linha com o valor total, e as anteriores ficarão ocultas e só serão exibidas por um toggle.

Eu devo utilizar o `nth-child` ou há outra maneira pra isso?

Comment: Qual/quais são as linhas "total" que queres mostrar? A + B ou a soma de A a F ?

Comment: As `TR` com `class="total"` são as que ficarão visíveis, @Sergio. As `TR` anteriores ficarão ocultas.

Comment: Apenas quando qualquer `TOTAL` for clicado, as `TR` anteriores a ela serão exibidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar assim:

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().each(function(){
        if (this.classList.contains('row-total')) return false;
        $(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

Usando o `.closest()` vais buscar o `tr` que contêm o `input` clicado.

Usando o `.prevAll()` vais buscar todos os `tr` anteriores.

Dar `return false;` dentro de um loop jQuery faz ele parar o loop, e portanto não ir procurar aos elementos anteriores.

Para esconder todos no inicio basta:

```
tr {
    display: none;
}
tr.row-total {
    display: block;
}
```

#### Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/4t8obg8y/1

Comment: Fiz um ajuste e voilà